# NumPy library ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, visual-studio, numpy, dll, importerror

I'm learning python using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. When I'm trying to import NumPy library into my code, this error appears. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, looking for `libiomp5md.dll` per instruction in [ImportError: DLL load failed when importing Numpy installed in conda virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778066/importerror-dll-load-failed-when-importing-numpy-installed-in-conda-virtual-env) but to no prevail.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adm\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Web Scraping\Web Scraping\Web_Scraping.py", line 17, in <module>
import numpy
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy. 
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all 
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: Make sure to use Python **3.6.1**. See [Python issue #29943](https://bugs.python.org/issue29943)

Answer (score 22):

I encountered the same problem with VSCode, and I resolved it by adding the following path to the system environment. After that restart VSCode and everything is OK.

`C:\Users\<Your user name>\Anaconda3\Library\bin`

If the anaconda was not installed in the default directory, please find your own `Anaconda3\Library\bin`.

Answer (score 8):

I've tried the following solution when I got the same issue for latest `numpy` version

1) Uninstall the `numpy` using `pip` as mentioned below:

`pip uninstall numpy`

Note: I've only Anaconda python v3.x installed in my system, so I'm using `pip`. If you've both `2.x` and `3.x` the use `pip3` to for this purpose.

2) Install `numpy 1.14.6` package using the below command

`pip install numpy==1.14.6`

This issue in the question is mentioned in the Github in the below link:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1508

Comment: doesn't help with python 2.7

Answer (score 6):

The newest version (in python 3) seems to be broken. Install an old version:

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
pip3 install 'numpy<1.13'
```

Keep in mind that was written in 2017. There might be a newer version that is not broken now.

Comment: I'm not able to install the package using the above commands. Can you revise them if possible?

Comment: doesn't help with python 2.7, it has no pip3

Comment: The question in the original post is for python3

Answer (score 5):

**First step** make sure VS code is able to find python and you are able to run simple

```
print("hello World!")  # without any imports, makes sure vscode is able to find python
```

refer to [How to setup VS code to find python3 on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313903/how-to-setup-visual-studio-code-to-find-python-3-interpreter-in-windows-10)

**Second step**

Review error message properly and note the path pointing to numpy location. in my case it is **C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core**
This is conda base environment and you have to upgrade numpy here. If your location is different , then you need to remove/update numpy in corresponding environment path.

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\pie_chart.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
```

[image]

Refer to image above , in my case error message in vscode pointed to following path **C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core**. This path corresponds to conda Base environment. To verify just do a pip install numpy and it will tell you the path, make sure you launch **Anaconda prompt** in administrator mode and do a **pip install in conda prompt**.
Once I made sure the path ( i.e. environment) where I am installing packages is same as in the  error message.I ran below commands( add packages as per your error messages)

`

```
#Run below commands in conda command prompt using administrator mode
pip uninstall numpy  
pip uninstall scipy

pip install numpy --upgrade
pip install scipy --upgrade
```

Following this procedure resolved my error.

Comment: I couldn't use sklearn or seaborn, and that was because spicy installation was corrupt for some reason. `pip install scipy --upgrade` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this issue, and what worked for me was to switch my default shell from powershell to "command prompt".

I tested this with separate powershell and command prompt windows. Not sure why powershell fails at this, must be some sort of path issue.

Comment: This was the case for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063285/numpy-is-already-installed-with-anaconda-but-i-get-an-importerror-dll-load-fail/58194133#58194133)

You need to update your environment variable "PATH" adding **\Library\bin**

Note: Follow this step only if you have already installed numpy and still facing issue.

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python<version>\Library\bin
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda<version>\Library\bin\
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error on `Windows10`, `Anaconda3` `64bits` evn `python=3.6`. I solved using `conda install numpy` instead of `pip...`

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered such problem after reinstalling a fresh windows 10.
My path and everything was all good (as mentioned by others above).
I even checked the path inside the python (by printing os.environ.get('PATH')). All good but numpy was complaining. I did whatever I did on previous win10.
On my previous win10 I had `Anaconda3`, and had created a new environment with numpy and other packages that I needed, all working well. I did the same on my new fresh win10, except I installed `Miniconda3` rather than Anaconda3.
Anyway, this fixed the problem:

- Switch to `base` env (conda activate base)
- install numpy in `base` (conda install numpy)
- and switch back to my_env (with numpy already installed there)
  Apparently with Miniconda, although you have numpy at your env (and when you're in that env, already the related paths get added to windows-environment), still numpy is looking for some dependency in the `base` env.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah guys, the answer is to go to *Settings - Advance system settings - Environment variables* and add `C:\Users\"username"\Anaconda3\Library\bin`

Then you restart it.