# Conda activate not working?

Tags: anaconda, conda

```
 gonzo  ~/a/packages  conda env list
# conda environments:
#
ppo_latest               /nohome/jaan/abhishek/anaconda3/envs/ppo_latest
root                  *  /nohome/jaan/abhishek/anaconda3

 gonzo  ~/a/packages  conda activate ppo_latest
 gonzo  ~/a/packages  which python                                                                                     (ppo_latest)
/nohome/jaan/abhishek/anaconda3/bin/python
 gonzo  ~/a/packages  conda deactivate                                                                                 (ppo_latest)
 gonzo  ~/a/packages  which python
/nohome/jaan/abhishek/anaconda3/bin/python
```

The environment gets activated without an error. Then we check which python it is referring to it. It is doesn't change, why?

Comment: Did you check your env folder? Mine was empty because i didnt provide a python version. If its empty gets activated but theres no python.

Comment: use this in your cmd: 
 ```activate <envname> ```

Comment: For others who are experiencing this problem, the problem could also be this known bug: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9392

Comment: Closing the current terminal and opening another one worked for me.

Comment: As @Julian mentions, I discovered that if I didn't create the environment with an explicit Python version then it simply defaults to something like `/usr/bin/python` rather than using the base env Python version. This is an unexpected new behavior that seems more like a bug.

Answer (score 158):

As of conda 4.4, the command

```
conda activate <envname>
```

is the same on all platforms. The procedure to add `conda` to the `PATH` environment variable for non-Windows platforms (on Windows you should use the Anaconda Prompt), as well as the change in environment activation procedure, is detailed in the [release notes](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.4.0) for conda 4.4.0.

---

For conda versions older than 4.4, command is either

```
source activate <envname>
```

on Linux and macOS or

```
activate <envname>
```

on Windows. You need to remove the `conda`.

Comment: Can't use source with fish.

Comment: Then you need to add that requirement into your post.

Comment: Also, according to this post, `source` is the correct command: https://superuser.com/a/84624/229278 You might need to install some additional dependencies: https://superuser.com/a/1235985/229278

Comment: I found this question after getting `CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.` on windows. The fix is to use `activate ...` instead of `conda activate ...`

Comment: @cedd Your edit is not correct. The new command is `conda activate` and is the same on all the platforms. I'm not sure what conda version you have, but that sounds like a separate question

Comment: @darthbith. It's your answer, and I'm not a python expert, so do what you think is best. However, I have conda 4.5.4 on windows, and for me `conda activate ...` returns the CommandNotFoundError, whereas `activate ...` works as I would expect.

Comment: @cedd Are you using Powershell? Powershell is not supported: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/626 You have to use the Anaconda Prompt. Also the [release notes](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.4.0) for conda 4.4 explicitly say that `conda activate` is the new way.

Comment: @darthbith: Fair enough, I believe you! I was probably using git bash, but it might have been the windows 10 command prompt (definitely not powershell). Maybe I should be using the Anaconda prompt ...

Comment: This unfortunately does not answer the question.

Comment: -1 for not quoting the relevant part of the release notes. The point of SO answers is to not read external, giant walls of texts

Comment: @Gulzar Please feel free to edit the answer to include that, if you would find it valuable...

Comment: If `conda activate` isn't available, use `conda init` and restart the shell. However, in my case, this doesn't work on my HPC cluster, so instead I used `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"` instead.

Answer (score 73):

I just ran into a similar issue.
Recently started developing on windows, so getting used to the PowerShell.
Ironically when trying to use 'conda activate ' in Git-bash i got the error

```
$ conda activate obf

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - cmd.exe
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

Running the command in my PowerShell (elevated) as instructed did the trick for me.

```
conda init powershell
```

This should be true across all terminal environments, just strange PowerShell didn't return this error itself.

Comment: When I had the same error in another context, I followed 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537131/numpy-library-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be

and there the answer of @User1024, adding a Path variable.

Comment: Wow! Had tried 1000 things, but FINALLY your tip worked. I just had to start my bat file with CALL conda.bat activate <my conda env name>.

Comment: After performing `conda init` in my cmd, conda activate worked, thanks the answer

Comment: Tkx brow, it solved my issue.

Answer (score 37):

To use "conda activate" via **Windows CMD, not the Anaconda Prompt**: 
(in response to okorng's question, although using the Anaconda Prompt is the preferred option)

First, we need to add the activate.bat script to your path: 
Via CMD:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;<your_path_to_anaconda_installation>\Scripts
```

Or via Control Panel, open "User Accounts" and choose "Change my environment variables".

Then calling directly from Windows CMD:

```
activate <environment_name>
```

without using the prefix "conda".

(Tested on Windows 7 Enterprise with Anaconda3-5.2.0)

Comment: Note that you need to have administrator privileges to accomplish this. If you add the path using the process above without admin privileges, it will not raise an error. However, if you close and re-open the command prompt, and run ```echo %PATH%```, your change will not be there.

Comment: @Foggy You can also add the Anaconda\Scripts PATH to your "user environment variables" without having admin rights (both on Win 7 & Win 10). These will then "persist" for new command prompts (after the first log-out / restart of your machine).

Comment: @stephinity thanks this is the only solution that worked for me, on Windows 10 environment.

Answer (score 31):

The anaconda functions are not exported by default, it can be done by using the following command:

```
source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

conda activate my_env
```

Comment: Worked, miniconda users use this `source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`

Answer (score 18):

As of conda 4.10.1, here is what worked for me using the Git Bash terminal in Sublime text 3 (same for cmd and Git cmd) on Windows:

```
$ source activate env_name
```

for me: `$ activate env_name` and `$ conda activate env_name` did not work!

to check the list of activated conda environments, in my case I use

```
$ conda env list
```

or

```
$ conda info --envs
```

the activated environment is preceded by *

note that I have already added anaconda to my path.

Comment: It worked for me , the best solution I've found until now.(I'm using Google Cloud Platform).

Comment: this worked for me in 09/2023

Answer (score 17):

- run `conda init` in cmd
- restart cmd
- run `conda activate envName`

Answer (score 11):

If your console does not show `(base)` after running `conda activate base`, then try running:

`conda init`

Then running `conda activate <your_env>` should show the name of `(<your_env>)` at the beginning of the shell prompt.

This worked for me on Windows. My PATH environment variable was set properly so `conda activate base` did not raise any error but quietly failed.

Answer (score 10):

I just created a new environment with conda and things are different. My `sys.path` was not correct for a bit until I figured out way.

As a result, I want to point out for anyone else confused by a change in `conda`, that if you have upgraded conda and created an environment, it will now tell you (as opposed to previous behavior):

```
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate test
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate
```

Thus, the *new* way to activate/deactivate environments is to do it like the above.

Indeed, if you upgrade from an older version of conda and you try the above, you may see the following helpful message (which I did):

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user with

    $ echo ". ~/anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile

or, for all users, enable conda with

    $ sudo ln -s ~/anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh

The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but they do NOT
put conda's base (root) environment on PATH.  To do so, run

    $ conda activate

in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently, run

    $ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bash_profile

Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to modify PATH in
your ~/.bash_profile file.  You should manually remove the line that looks like

    export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bash_profile file! ^^^
```

Changing the above fixed my issues with `sys.path` in activated conda environments.

Comment: The above instructions assume Mac/Linux env with the reference to a Bash or Bourne variant shell.  What about for the standard Windows CMD shell?   My miniconda3/etc/profile.d  folder only has conda.sh and conda.csh files, but no Windows conda.bat version.  Does one exist to support these instructions?  Thanks.

Comment: I followed these instructions and I'm still getting that error, even though conda seems to be working otherwise. It's very strange.

Answer (score 10):

```
conda init
```

Run this in command prompt.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
export PATH=/home/your_username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
in ~/.bashrc
```

Then `source ~/.bashrc`
This works for me for the same problem.

Comment: This is an answer for installations where there is no home folder as well.
Sometimes there's only a root "user" and no home directory.
Just add the path to miniconda/bin or anaconda3/bin (whereever you might have installed it) to $PATH and it should start running.
e.g. `export PATH=/root/minconda3/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 5):

In the windows environment use "anaconda prompt" instead of "command prompt".

Comment: Thanks. In Powershell on Windows 10, nothing happened, no error message but also no environment activation. Using the "anaconda prompt" worked.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the change of default terminal to command promt (cmd.exe) did a trick. VS Code - Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue but For linux this worked :
in terminal Type:

```
$ bash
$ conda init
$ cd /path_that_include_env_dir
$ conda activate ./<env_name>
```

or

```
$ conda activate /env_path
```

"env_path" is full environment path as : /home/usr/env_dir

> To check environments list and their paths
> $ conda env list

Answer (score 2):

For windows, Use the Anaconda Powershell Prompt and `conda` command to activate the virtual environment

[image]

Comment: "Use the Anaconda Powershell Prompt" to do what?

Comment: This is what worked for me. Just use the Anaconda Prompt shell to do all command you would otherwise use in CMD. Windows 11 user here.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this command in your cmd:

`activate <envname>`

Works like charm!
**(worked for windows, don't know about mac)**

Answer (score 2):

go settings and change "shell path" to "cmd" from power shell.
i'm using pycharm on windows 10, and that fixed my prolem.
settings>tools>terminal>shell path>cmd

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**This solution is for those users who do not want to set PATH.**

Sometimes setting PATH may not be desired. In my case, I had Anaconda installed and another software with a Python installation required for accessing the API, and setting PATH was creating conflicts which were difficult to resolve.

Under the `Anaconda` directory (in this case Anaconda3) there is a subdirectory called `envs` where all the environments are stored. When using `conda activate some-environment` replace `some-environment` with the actual directory location of the environment.

In my case the command is as follows.

`conda activate C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\some-environment`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me  using the **Git Bash terminal in VS Code** on windows in succinct steps:

1. `source activate env-name` - You should see your line appended by the (base) tag now.
2. After calling on `source activate`, I've found following `conda activate` commands to work: i.e. `conda activate env2-name`

What didn't work for Git Bash (as a VS Code terminal) for me: `activate env-name` and `conda activate env-name`.

Not exactly sure why this specific behaviour occurs on the Git Bash terminal on VS Code, but the accepted answer + this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57560017/stuck-when-setting-up-to-use-anaconda-with-vs-code-and-integrated-git-terminal) I've found might provide clues.

Answer (score 1):

After installing conda in Linux if you are trying to create env just type bash and hit Enter later you can create env

Answer (score 1):

I changed my shell from `bash` to `zsh` according to Apple prompt message and restarted the terminal, and it works for me after doing this.

Comment: This is awesome

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works for you, you can specify the full path of your python environment setup by conda.

For me, I set up an environment called "testenv" using conda.

I searched all python environments using

```
whereis python | grep 'miniconda'
```

It returned a list of python environments. Then I ran my_python_file.py using the following command.

```
~/miniconda3/envs/testenv/bin/python3.8 my_python_file.py
```

You can do the same thing on windows too but looking up for python and conda python environments is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with **Anaconda command prompt** or, **cmd** it works for me. Giving no error and activation is not working in PowerShell may be some path issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hello let me share what worked for me. **(WINDOWS USERS)**

1. Add conda to path(that is to your environment variables - the scripts folder to be precise) i.e. **C:\Users\kboys\anaconda3\Scripts**
2. Reopen your cmd, type activate and the name of your target environment, i.e

`$ activate <env_name>`

`$ activate tensorflow`

Note this way you don't need to call conda.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new environment in miniconda, but when trying to activate it in VSCode's terminal, it gives this

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'. If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.
```

Then I found in the VSCode settings this option, `terminal.integrated.shellArgs`:

[image: Terminal options]

By default, it is 'null', but changing it to 'Command Prompt', it made the 'conda activate [my env]' command in the VSCode terminal work.

Answer (score 0):

For using anaconda activate in Windows cmd/terminal
just simple `Run as Administrator`

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2023, I installed Anaconda and created a new environment. IT worked perfectly fine from the windows PowerShell. It showed that I could now activate the environment with Conda activate  but when I ran the command, it didn't work.

All I had to do was run the following command in windows PowerShell (as Jordan has mentioned):

```
conda init
```

After that, the windows PowerShell will show you a notice to restart the PowerShell, once I restarted it, it was working fine, and I was able to activate/deactivate my environments properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the error

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
```

even after I had used `conda init bash` and restarted my shell.

In the end, it turned out that I had not activated the conda base environment first, so my generated environment was lacking a Python version. When using

```
conda activate base
```

before creating the new environment, it worked for me.

The tell-tale sign is that `(base)` is not showing in your prompt when you create your new environment.

Answer (score -3):

set-executionpolicy remotesigned
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted

Comment: Please add formatting and an explanation.