# 'activate' is not a conda command - CommandNotFoundError

Tags: python

I didn't want to update VS code cause I worried if this thing might happen but it updated by itself and now I'm unable to run python on my laptop ever since then with this CommandNotFoundError.

The error message that I keep get is below:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Command Error: error with command 'activate'. Command not found: 'activate'. 'activate' is not a conda command.
```

my python path is PS C:\Users\user> & C:/Users/user/Anaconda3/pythonw.exe 
and I had no problem with running python before the update now I don't really know how to solve this error.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me with this!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246350/conda-activate-not-working

Comment: Can you share some more information on your environment?

Comment: @AMC I was looking into the same thing but I didn't really understand the post since I'm new to python and programing. Would you be kind enough to let me know what information I need to share more to solve this? :)

Comment: Your OS, Conda version, how you have VS code setup, etc.

Comment: @AMC My OS is window 10 and Anaconda is version 4.2.0. And I have anaconda and python in it but I just learned that I have another python located in programs with VS code. I actually don't know which one I used to use before the update. Should I just change the python path to one outside of conda?

Comment: It’s probably better to use Conda. Doesn’t VS Code include settings for using virtual environments?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the following:

```
source activate <environment name>
```

it did the trick for me. I am using Vis Code on Windows 11, using Remote SSH to ssh into my RB pi3B which runs on a miniconda.