# Working with Anaconda in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I am getting a bit confused here, the latest Anaconda Distribution, 2018.12 at time of writing comes with an option to install Microsoft Visual Studio Code, which is great.

When launching VSC and after `Python: Select Interpreter` and with a fresh install of Anaconda, I can see `~Anaconda3\python.exe` which I assume is the Anaconda Python Environment, however, when I try to run some commands, I am getting:

```
PS ~\Documents\Python Scripts\vs> ~/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate
PS ~\Documents\Python Scripts\vs> conda activate base
```

> conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At line:1 char:1

Now I know that it might be related to the environment variables but I find it highly odd as during the Anaconda installation, there are specific mentions that it is not required to add the Anaconda path to the environment variables. However after the error, the integrated terminal manages to launch Python and I am able to run code.

Next in line is that I am unable to view any variables in the debugger after running a simple script, as shown in the tutorial [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial):

```
msg = "Hello World"
print(msg)
```

I do expect to see similar results as shown in the link such as the dunder variables, I have also updated my `launch.json` with `stopOnEntry = True` following the steps.

I would like to know if it is possible to use Visual Studio Code with Anaconda as a interpreter without registering variables from the original distribution and if I am missing out anything required.

I expected the experience to be more straight forward but also I might be missing something, I am running on *Windows 10.*

Comment: just wondering if it is worth updating the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Activating a conda environment does not place `conda` on your `PATH`. You need to launch the `Anaconda Prompt` app from your Start menu to get a command-line with `conda` on your `PATH` if you didn't check the box to include `conda` during installation.

Also realize that `conda` only supports PowerShell as of `conda` 4.6 which was released in January 2019.

And the Python extension for VS Code works with `conda` fine. Create a `conda` environment and the extension will allow you to select it as your environment/interpreter.

Comment: I figure out as much, thought that there might have been some magic functions working behind that temporarily adds to `PATH`. So if I understand correctly, the method that works is to launch VS Code via Anaconda Prompt/Navigator > Select interpreter  > Select Environment and code away?

Comment: If you want to have `conda` in the terminal, then yes, that should work. If you don't care about having `conda` in the integrated terminal then simply launch VS Code as normal and you can always open the Anaconda Prompt next to VS Code.

Comment: I'd argue that if you have to launch vscode itself from within the conda environment to properly define all the PATH variables there shouldn't be a need to actually select the interpreter from within vscode. The location of the appropriate python executable is already defined in the conda environment.

This is definitely a flaw in vscode design. There should be a way to provide full conda support without bogging the user down by having them start an anaconda terminal and open vscode from there for everything to work...

Comment: @user32882 no one is arguing with you on that and we are actively working on improving it (the new code is already out for A/B experiment and if you use our insiders build you can get it right now). But also note that making conda work is not simple for various reasons that SO's character count limit makes hard to get into. But do know we are doing the best we can.

Answer (score 181):

I beat my head on this for far too long... launching VS Code from an Anaconda Prompt both feels clunky and didn't really work for integrated Powershell terminals (the default VS Code integrated terminal on Windows)

I wanted to be able to launch VS Code from any prompt (and usually the Windows menu shortcut) and still interact with Conda.

These two methods both worked for Anaconda 2020.02, VS Code 1.44.0, on Windows 10.

### Easy & Quick

Switch VS Code to use cmd.exe as the default integrated terminal shell by:

1. opening the command palette (`Control-Shift-P`)
2. search for `Terminal: Select Default Profile`
3. select `Command Prompt`

### Harder / Powershell

1. add the location of `conda` to your PATH (if you did not add it via the installer). For me on an "All Users" install this is `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\Scripts`
2. from an Administrator Powershell prompt change the Powershell Execution Policy to remote signed i.e. `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`, or from a non-admin Powershell prompt change the Powershell Execution Policy to remote signed, that is, `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned`
3. open an Anaconda Prompt and run `conda init powershell` which will add Conda related startup to a Powershell profile.ps1 somewhere in your user's profile.

When you run VS Code and either debug a .py or launch a Powershell integrated terminal you should now see a message about "Loading personal and system profiles" and the Conda environment being prefixed on the terminal's prompt.

Comment: I can not find the `Command Prompt` option. I am using 
```
Version: 1.51.0
Commit: fcac248b077b55bae4ba5bab613fd6e9156c2f0c
Date: 2020-11-05T18:14:40.758Z (3 wks ago)
Electron: 9.3.3
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0
```

Comment: @JingpengWu if I am reading your versions right, it looks like you are trying to do this on a Mac? `Command Prompt` only applies to Windows afaik

Comment: thanks for checking this. Yes, I am using it on a Mac.

Comment: as of 05.21, "Select default shell' was changed to 'Select Default Profile'

Comment: @Sergio thx, updated the answer. i do feel this answer is getting slowly out of date as there are a lot of changes afoot in the way Python and Vscode interact!

Comment: What are the implications of allowing "RemoteSigned"? Is there a way to limit this to the scripts required for getting Conda to work in VSCode's Powershell?

Comment: Worked perfectly for me on Windows 11 as of 10/10/2021. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't read before starting, sadly, you cannot chose the 'harder' option (powershell) if you don't have admin rights on the windows box.

Comment: Does the harder (powershell) option has any advantages?

Comment: Still works as a charm on Windows 10 as of 21/06/2023. Ty!

Comment: Thanks @janh.   I followed your instructions for Powershell set up on my Win11 and 'conda' now works as desired.

Comment: My problem was on the contrary: my powershell activated the base env successfully and add the path to conda automatically. It caused the problem that prevent gdb from launching when I debug C++ code (because anaconda put its own mingw path at the front). I have to use cmd only. It there any way to have both coexist?

Answer (score 62):

For me, this solution worked in VSC (1.40) ->

1.Set the Interpreter to Python 3.7.1 ('base':conda) 

2. Rather than using PowerShell I switched (Select Default Shell) to Command Prompt and started a New Terminal -> now it's in conda (base) environment.

[for Anaconda Distribution, 2018.12]

Answer (score 34):

To set anaconda prompt as your default terminal in VScode:

> 1. (type)               CTRL + SHIFT + P
> 2. (search for:)        open settings
> 3. (click:)             Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)

Then add three line configuration:

```
{
    ... # any other settings you have already added (remove this line)

    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\Anaconda3"],
    "python.condaPath": "C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe"
}
```

***Finally, Restart your VScode***

Comment: if you installed Miniconda and/or as a User instead of Administrator then remember to update the shellArgs and condaPath appropriately. To find the .bat and .exe you can run 'where conda' in an Anaconda prompt outside of VS code. The other shellArg is the installation path for Anaconda or Miniconda

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me. Thank you!@Zhongyi.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, these lines give hover message "unsupported property".

Comment: VSCode tells me that this options are deprecated and that I should create a terminal profile. The solution of "blaylockbk" adds the profile to the settings

Comment: -1; You should make clear in the answer that `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` is deprecated and throws the warning `This is deprecated, use '#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#' instead`, see [Upgraded to version 1.56.0... Issues with terminal/Powershell #123066](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123066).

Answer (score 14):

Following the trails of @andre-barbosa and @kenlukas, the below configuration works well for me (PowerShell on Windows 10):

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "-ExecutionPolicy",
    "ByPass",
    "-NoExit",
    "-Command",
    "your-path-to-\\conda-hook.ps1",
    ";conda activate 'your-path-to-the-base-conda-environment'"
]
```

Substitute "*your-path-to-\conda-hook.ps1*" and "*your-path-to-the-base-conda-environment*" with your actual path, and add it to VSCode's `settings.json`. Check out the properties of your "Anaconda Powershell Prompt" shortcut and you'll find what you need.

The key is really to obey the rules of VSCode's JSON configuration file, by turning the whole arguments string into a comma separated list.

Comment: Can you tell me me how to configure the python Debugger (extension ms-python.python) such that this works as well?  Currently it seems like `conda` is found in my _Python_ Terminal, but not in my _Python Debug Console_ Terminal.

Comment: @MichaelKopp Not sure if this is possible. I played around with the debug config file `launch.json` a little, and it seems that the `console` field is constrained to one of the three values: `internalConsole`, `integratedTerminal`, and `externalTerminal`, and does not accept additional arguments.

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. Can confirm it  still works and resolved an issue I had with VS Code and mambaforge on Windows 11. The initial setting in the json file was wrongly formatted, not as an array.

Comment: -1; You should make clear in the answer that `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` is deprecated and throws the warning `This is deprecated, use '#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#' instead`, see [Upgraded to version 1.56.0... Issues with terminal/Powershell #123066](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123066).

Answer (score 11):

The `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows"` method is depreciated:

> This is deprecated, the new recommended way to configure your default shell is by creating a terminal profile in `#terminal.integrated.profiles.windows#` and setting its profile name as the default in `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#`.

After reading the [VS code docs (configuring profiles)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles), I created a new profile for the Anaconda Prompt. The following is what is in my `settings.json` file:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows":{
    "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
        "source": "Git Bash"
    },
    "Anaconda Prompt": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "args": [
            "powershell",
            "-NoExit",
            "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass",
            "-NoProfile",
            "-File C:\\path\\to\\Miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1"
        ],
        "icon": "smiley"
    }
}
```

Comment: Though the same as naylinn, I prefer this solution due to its readability. 

Using Anaconda, however, the args didn't work fully for me, and I didn't realize that the %USERNAME% wildcard didn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63591046/vs-code-username-wild-card-in-json-settings

For the last args element above, I'd have this instead:
"-Command",
"'& 'C:\\Users\\${env:USERNAME}\\Anaconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\\Users\\${env:USERNAME}\\Anaconda3''"

Comment: @Adji_PA your comment helped me!

Answer (score 10):

If you launch VS Code application from inside the Anaconda Navigator application, you automatically get a "conda-aware" VSCode integrated terminal.

This way you don't need to change the settings in VS Code itself.

Answer (score 9):

Adding this setting to settings.json solved for me:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
       "PowerShell -NoExit -File C:\\ProgramFiles\\Anaconda\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1"
    ]
```

PS: This answer is based on kenlukas's answer, but for powershell instead of cmd.

Comment: I had to add `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` to avoid errors about execution policies.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61402982/2165903

Comment: -1; You should make clear in the answer that `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` is deprecated and throws the warning `This is deprecated, use '#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#' instead`, see [Upgraded to version 1.56.0... Issues with terminal/Powershell #123066](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123066).

Answer (score 8):

### Command Prompt (default) stopped working for me Sept 2021

Originally I used the quick fix that many have suggested:

Terminal dropdown --> Select default profile --> Command Prompt

Not as good as PowerShell but like many of you I didn't care and just wanted to get on with my project.

Recently, VS Code updated and despite the above setting, PowerShell would run by default in terminal. Back to square one.

### The one-line fix

I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61879466/8515040) and tried the following in my Anaconda PowerShell Prompt (Miniconda3):

```
conda init
```

which changed several paths, including some used by PowerShell. Now Python scripts running in VS Code run in PowerShell because PowerShell now recognises Conda.

### Note

If you've created a virtual environment you still need to indicate this in VS Code:

View --> Command Palette... --> Python: Select Interpreter -->

```
~\Path\to\my\virtual\environment\python.exe
```

Comment: great answer, and do not forget to set powershell execution policy to "remote signed". `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Comment: Noob question - why?

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me a lot.

Comment: If you don't have admin rights, you will need this to remove the error when loading powershell

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser

Answer (score 7):

For me, [this article](https://medium.com/@udiyosovzon/how-to-activate-conda-environment-in-vs-code-ce599497f20d) solved my issue (on Windows 10):  Specifically, the settings.json entry: `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows` e.g.:

```
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/K", 
        "C:\\Programs\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat & conda activate py37"
    ]
```

It works well with command line but doesn't seem to work with PowerShell.

Comment: -1; You should make clear in the answer that `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` is deprecated and throws the warning `This is deprecated, use '#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#' instead`, see [Upgraded to version 1.56.0... Issues with terminal/Powershell #123066](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123066).

Answer (score 5):

As many have pointed out, you can simply launch "code" from the Anaconda Command Prompt (ACP).

The ACP is simply a shortcut to a Command Prompt (and equivalently on powershell) with some arguments. (e.g. `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`)

As @janh pointed out, it is annoying to launch vscode from there each time, instead, you can change the default within the VS Code setting.json file, as @zonhgyi pointed out, but what he recommended is/will be deprecated.

REF: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration

Here's what I ended up using.  No need to change PATH, no need to make other changes than editing the settings.json file (which can be accessed through Ctrl+Shift+P -> settings.json)

```
...

"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "Conda": {
    "path": "C:\\windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "args": [
      "/K", "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3"
    ],
    "icon": "squirrel"
  }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Conda", 
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Open file `C:\Users\YOUR-USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`

Insert section `"Miniconda3": { }`

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {

    "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },

    "Miniconda3": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "args": "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command \"& 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3' \"",
        "icon": "C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\conda\\shell\\conda_icon.ico"
    },

    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },

    "Git Bash": {
        "source": "Git Bash"
    }

}
```

No need to touch `env:PATH`

Btw, `Miniconda3.args` is copied from `Anaconda Powershell Prompt (Miniconda3) -> Properties.Shortcut.Target`

If you are using Anaconda instead of Miniconda, you may want to modify a few paths.

VS Code is just an editor, Python Extension keeps breaking stuff, and spreads its config files everywhere. Stopped using long time ago.

Comment: I am trying this in VS Code 1.60 and now it requires the "args" to be an array. However, when I enclose the string in [] I get an error saying "The argument '-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit... is not recognized as the name of a script file".

Comment: @Neits it should be the command line that executes your anaconda prompt from powershell. Naylinn suggests to get it from the properties of your Anaconda prompt application (find icon, right click then properties and target)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a better way, to let conda work with powershell in vscode, without change your PATH, which is unrecommanded:

1. <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, open terminal as Administrator.
2. run `C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe init powershell`, you can use `where conda` in Anaconda Prompt (anaconda3) to find the path.

It works for me. May be run `conda.exe init powershell` in Anaconda Prompt (anaconda3) directly is also helpful, but I haven't try it.

Comment: I can confirm that if you run `conda.exe init powershell` from the Anaconda Prompt directly it will work.

Answer (score 3):

I am working on VS Version: 1.47.0 (user setup).
I recently switched from Jupyter Notebook (still working there for my reports) to VS Code. But my codes were not running. Same problem of  'conda' is not recognized. What worked for me was:

1. Kill Terminal and start afresh
2. In the terminal dropdown option, selected "Select Default Shell"
3. Changed that from powershell to CMD.
4. Now all my preinstalled libraries and conda working perfectly fine.

Comment: Correct, this does work, change to CMD shell, and will start conda AND activate your miniconda environment, after your selected your interpreter (env). No need to set 'Python: Conda Path' in your settings

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to open anaconda shell prompt, then launch VScode from that terminal. Now VScode can see everthing from anaconda!

Answer (score 3):

A combination of the above examples and some recent profile creation worked best for me.  I didn't want to replace the existing default profile, just add a new one with the right environment settings.

Go into user settings and find a link to 'edit settings json' (there's one in the extensions section).

Add a profile in the terminal.integrated.profiles.windows object:

```json
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
      ],
      "args": [],
      "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
      "source": "Git Bash"
    },
    "Anaconda PS Prompt": {
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
      "args": [
        "-ExecutionPolicy",
        "ByPass",
        "-NoExit",
        "-Command",
        "& 'C:\\Users\\me\\anaconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1'",
        "; conda activate 'C:\\Users\\me\\anaconda3'"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Save the file and it should immediately be available in the terminal drop-down.  If not, restart VS Code.

NOTE: I got my 'args' above from the Anaconda Prompt shortcut, just go to the file location and check properties (it's a .lnk file if you're using a start menu shortcut, so you need to see where that is pointing).

Answer (score 3):

This is for Windows only. This also assumes a default installation of Anaconda or Miniconda. Add the following to your User Settings (ctrl-shift-p -> Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON) option) ...

```
{   
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Anaconda CMD": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [
            "/K",
            "C:\\Users\\${env:USERNAME}\\AppData\\Local\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat & conda activate base"
        ],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Anaconda PS": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "args": [
            "powershell",
            "-NoExit",
            "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass",
            "-NoProfile",
            "-Command",
            "'& 'C:\\Users\\${env:USERNAME}\\AppData\\Local\\Anaconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1'; conda activate base'"
        ],
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Anaconda CMD"
```

This will add two options, a powershell conda terminal and a windows command prompt conda terminal. It sets the command prompt conda terminal option to default (ctrl+` in VS code) and activates the base environment.

You can flavor the conda environment you want to start in to taste (replace "base" with your env name). You can also set the prompt you want to use as default.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux (since all of the answers seem to show the way for Windows):

1. Install the Microsoft Extension "Python extension for Visual Studio Code"
2. `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` -> `Python: Select Interpreter`

[image]

But this throws an error:

[image]

> Command: 'Python: Select Interpreter' resulted in an error. Command
> 'python.setinterpreter' not found.

Restarting VSCode was not enough, I had to restart the computer. Then, it worked:

[image]

I could choose the conda base environment. After adding another virtual env, I could also choose that.

This looks like on Windows, but I wanted to prove this on Linux as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click control+shift+p
2. Search Teminal: Select Default profile
3. Open new terminal (python recent virtual environment)
4. Again click control+shift+p
5. Search Python: Select Interpreter  (choose your environment or base conda environment)
6. Open new terminal (conda virtual environment)

Answer (score 1):

For me my interpreter was set to a different version:

CTRL+SHIFT+P -> Select Python: Select Interpreter

Select the latest version.

Comment: but that I can't use that Python in the terminal. It can only click on the run button with a default interpreter. What if you have argument parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to add 4~5 path in environment variable

[image]

somebody may not have `.../usr/bin`. it's not important.

and secondly, you have to change default profile to command prompt in vs code.
Using default shell or power shell would have some problem.
in my case , I can't activate `conda` environment which I created.
it keep stop in the (base) env of anaconda.
press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> select `terminal:select default profile` and click.
Then choose command prompt.
when changing into command prompt, I can use `activate (myenvname)` to other env.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3
C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\Library\bin

Just add these three path to your Path

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have anaconda installed, open the "Command Prompt" terminal:

1. /Users/NAME/anaconda3/Scripts/activate

This will activate conda prompt, and you can continue to select, create, deactivate any environment you want. Make sure to specify the path to anaconda3 (replace NAME)

Answer (score 0):

Find the Anaconda Path in you system using

```
where anaconda
```

it would give result like

```
C:\Users\Something\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda.exe
```

add this to your computer path variable via edit path variable. and add till

```
C:\Users\Something\AppData\Local\anaconda3 .
```

Now restart vscode and everything shall work.