# VS Code %USERNAME% Wild Card in JSON Settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the Windows Command Prompt, I can enter:

```
cd \Users\%USERNAME%
```

And it takes me to my user's home directory, e.g.: C:\User\MyName.

But in Visual Studio Code's JSON settings, the following doesn't resolve:

```
{
    "jshint.config": "C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\JSHint.json",
}
```

Is there a trick to getting %USERNAME% to resolve in the JSON settings? Do I need to escape the percentage signs somehow? Or does the %USERNAME% wildcard simply doesn't work in VS Code?

Comment: `USERNAME` is an environment variable. These can be referenced in visual studio code as follows: `${env:USERNAME}`.

See the [documentation][1] for further details.


  [1]: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables

Comment: I tried `"jshint.config": "C:\\Users\\${env:USERNAME}\\JSHint.json"` but it didn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like I pointed you to the wrong documentation, sorry. The one I mentioned, only addresses variable substitution in Debugging and Task configuration files. Actually there is an [open issue][1] concerning variable substitution in vs code settings.
[1]: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code's JSON settings, you cannot use environment variable references (such as `%USERNAME%`) directly in the JSON file. JSON settings in VS Code do not support environment variable expansion.

If you want to include the path to your user's home directory in your settings, you can achieve this by using a dynamic value from a VS Code variable instead. VS Code provides built-in variables that you can use for various purposes, including accessing the user's home directory. The variable you need for this is `${workspaceFolder}`.

Here's an example of how you can set your `jshint.config` to a path within your user's home directory in your `settings.json` file:

`{ "jshint.config": "${workspaceFolder}\\JSHint.json" }`

This will create a path relative to your workspace folder. If you want to specify an absolute path within your user's home directory, you can use the `~` symbol, which represents the user's home directory:

`{ "jshint.config": "~\\JSHint.json" }`

The `~` symbol, when used in this context in VS Code settings, will automatically resolve to your user's home directory.

Keep in mind that the `~` symbol might not work in all settings or extensions, but it works in some contexts within VS Code settings.

I think this will help you...

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?