# How to use Anaconda Python from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda

When I start Visual Studio Code from Anaconda, it runs my python code without problems. When I start VSC from Windows Start Menu, it doesn't.

#### What I know so far:

- In Anaconda's User Preferences ('*Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)'*), the path points to the same installation of VSC as in the Start Menu. It seems as if Anaconda is starting VSC in a different way, because VSC uses a different theme when I start it via Start Menu or via Anaconda, so there are two differnet files for VS Code's User preferences. One resides in `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`, the other in `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\.anaconda\navigator\Code\User\settings.json`.
- In '*Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)*' I set `python.condaPath`, `python.defaultInterpreterPath` and `python.pythonPath` to the same values and also the other settings are set to the same values (except for `workbench.colorTheme`) for both instances.
- When I run python code, both instances use PowerShell, but starting via Anaconda recognizes the `conda` command and starting via Start Menu, `conda` is not found.
- I discovered some additional environmental variables defined by Anaconda (run `Get-ChildItem Env:` in PowerShell). 'UWO' is the name of the selected anaconda environment:

```
PROMPT                         (UWO) (UWO) $P$G
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV              UWO
CONDA_EXE                      C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
CONDA_PREFIX                   C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\UWO
CONDA_PREFIX_2                 C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3
CONDA_PREFIX_3                 C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\UWO
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER          (UWO)
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE               C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\python.exe
CONDA_ROOT                     C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3
CONDA_SHLVL                    3
```

- Additionally, there is much more in the path (run `(Get-ChildItem Env:\Path).Value` in PowerShell):

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\UWO;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\UWO\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\UWO\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\UWO\Library\bin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\UWO\Scripts;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\UWO\bin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\condabin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Library\bin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Scripts;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\bin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\condabin;
```

#### What did I try?

There are multiple suggestions to fix similar/same issues, but none of the one I found fixed my issue nor explains what is going on. [This suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61300365) got close: run `conda init powershell` in an Anaconda Prompt and set the proper permissions by running `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser` from an Administrator PowerShell. With this, `conda` is found when VSC is started from Start Menu, but the environment is not changed when running python: PowerShell always prompts (base), `conda info --envs` reports that it is using 'base' environment, and using `import os; print(os.path.basename(os.environ.get('CONDA_PREFIX', None)))` from python also reveals the (wrong) 'base' environment for VSC started via Start Menu and the expected 'UWO' when started from Anaconda.

With this command, these environmental variables are added:

```
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV              base
CONDA_EXE                      C:\Users\pern\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
CONDA_PREFIX                   C:\Users\pern\AppData\Local\anaconda3
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER          (base)
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE               C:\Users\pern\AppData\Local\anaconda3\python.exe
CONDA_SHLVL                    1
```

Except for the SHLVL value, the environmental variables are the same in both VSC instances. As far as I understand, having a SHLVL value of 1 should be fine, as only one environment should be active at one time. Setting it to 3 in an `.env` file in the workspace did not help.

Also the path has beed modified to include

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Library\bin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Scripts;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\bin;
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\condabin;
```

To me it seems the path is set correctly, because when a new environment is added in Anaconda, the path in VSC started from Anaconda does not include the `\envs\NewEnv\`-parts.

Note to my later self: to revert the changes, issue `Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Scope CurrentUser` and delete `Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`.

#### How to setup VSC properly?

I never read that Visual Studio Code only works with Anaconda when it is started through Anaconda, so there seems to be something wrong with my setup. In the moment, the only fix I see is to start VSC from Anaconda, which is not so convenient.

Any suggestions on how to setup Visual Studio Code to work properly with Anaconda when started from Start Menu?