# Using boost numpy with visual studio 2019 and python 3.8

Tags: python, numpy, boost

I want to use Boost Numpy (boost version 1.72) with Visual Studio 2017 and Python 3.8. In my test program which includes I get a link error "boost_numpy38-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_72.lib". I cannot find the file "boost_numpy38-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_72.lib" anywhere, it is not created when building the binaries (bootstrap + .\b2) and it is nowhere to be found on the binary repositories at Sourceforge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/ ).

Anybody any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building Boost using the boostrap + .\b2 method will check to make sure that you have numpy installed before building boost_numpy. Make sure that you have numpy installed (`python -m pip install numpy`).

On my machine, the exact command used by b2 to check if numpy is installed is:

`python -c "import sys; sys.stderr = sys.stdout; import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())"`

You can check the command on your own machine by adding `--debug-configuration` to the .\b2 command, but it should be the same.

Numpy must be installed for whichever version of Python is used for the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Tnx Layne, that was indeed the clue!!

In addition some other clues:
- run 'bootstrap vc141' if you have multiple VS installation and you want to use 2017
- run 'b2.exe --build-type=complete' to get both static and dynamic libraries

Once everything is build you will need
boost_numpy38-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_72.dll and boost_python38-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_72.dll to run your program