# python.exe flashes and close while running from windows scheduler

Tags: windows, anaconda, windows-task-scheduler, python-exec

python.exe flashes and close while running from windows scheduler

 Last run result is showing : (0x1)

*Everything was working perfect untill i uninstall and reinstall anaconda.

 New reinstalled Anaconda3 folder is at same place.

 Jupyter notebook and other stuffs are working fine except this Windows Scheduler.*

 Below image shows windows scheduler configuration.

PS. Program/script: path is : C:\Users\SBA25\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe

[image]

Comment: Can you please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code please?

Comment: @Jamie pls check. Ive attached an image

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

What is i did is: Made a batch file with code :

```
"C:\Users\SBA25\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\python_scripts\xml_to_csv.py"
pause
```

Then i run it and it got the error details : Which was saying me about numpy module not found error.
Which got resolved by adding system path to System Env Variable : [Answer in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063285/numpy-is-already-installed-with-anaconda-but-i-get-an-importerror-dll-load-fail)