# ARCPRO notebook import numpy error: DLL load failed

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook, arcgis, arcpy

with arcgis pro 2.9 environment, error from notebook when import numpy shown below. I understand this can be fixed by adding system path, such as solution from here [numpy is already installed with Anaconda but I get an ImportError (DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063285/numpy-is-already-installed-with-anaconda-but-i-get-an-importerror-dll-load-fail), however, this is for ARCGIS pro, not anaconda environment, also I don't have admin right to the laptop, thanks for the help in advance.

```
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:


and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```