# Importing Kmeans from sklearn suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I've loaded my Jupyter notebook as usual, when the only thing I changed is the Numpy version to 1.21.4.

**However** once I imported Kmeans `from sklearn.cluster import KMeans` I received the following error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing lapack_lite: The specified module could not be found.

I've tried the solution given in the link here, but it didn't help: [ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

I've also tried to reinstall scikit-learn, but it also didn't help. So did restarting the kernel and the notebook didn't help.

My scikit-learn version is `1.1.1`

I code on the same code on my laptop and on my desktop PC. On my laptop the code runs good the this specific import won't produce this error. But on my desktop PC, it does produce this error, which is strange because the scikit-learn and numpy versions are the same on both my desktop PC and laptop.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537131/numpy-library-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063285/numpy-is-already-installed-with-anaconda-but-i-get-an-importerror-dll-load-fail) works? 

What are you using anaconda or pip? In any situation try creating a new virtual environment with freshly installed dependencies...