# Loaded 'qgis' package with Anaconda, importing gives the error "DLL load failed while importing _analysis: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, pyqgis

My goal is to edit and run qgis scripts in Spyder. I installed Anaconda. Within Anaconda Navigator I created an environment 'qgis_env' with Python 3.9.15, and installed the `qgis` package in the environment. Then I installed Spyder in the environment and opened Spyder from that environment. `import qgis` appears to run fine. However any `import` statement that involves a subpackage like `import qgis.analysis` or `from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer` gives an error `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _analysis: The specified module could not be found.`

Things I have tried:

1. Uninstalled Anaconda, and also uninstalled any other related but unnecessary standalone installs I already had: QGIS, Python, IDLE, and Spyder. Reinstalled Anaconda and recreated the qgis environment as above.
2. Checked `~\anaconda3\envs\qgis_env\Library\python\qgis\`. This folder does contain files called `_analysis.pyd`, `_analysis.pyi`, `_core.pyd`, etc. `~\anaconda3\envs\qgis_env\Library\python` was included in `PYTHONPATH` by default.
3. Based on a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537131/numpy-library-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be) to mine, added `~\anaconda3\envs\qgis_env\Library\bin` to `PYTHONPATH`. This folder contains files like `qgis_analysis.dll`.
4. Tried `import` statements in JupyterLab.

It is possible that I am missing something basic about Anaconda environments and importing packages/subpackages, but I really thought that I was using these tools the way they are meant to be used. Any help is appreciated.

Things I have tried:

1. Uninstalled Anaconda, and also uninstalled any other related but unnecessary standalone installs I already had: QGIS, Python, IDLE, and Spyder. Reinstalled Anaconda and recreated the qgis environment as above.
2. Checked `~\anaconda3\envs\qgis_env\Library\python\qgis\`. This folder does contain files called `_analysis.pyd`, `_analysis.pyi`, `_core.pyd`, etc. `~\anaconda3\envs\qgis_env\Library\python` was included in `PYTHONPATH` by default.
3. Based on a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537131/numpy-library-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be) to mine, added `~\anaconda3\envs\qgis_env\Library\bin` to `PYTHONPATH`. This folder contains files like `qgis_analysis.dll`.
4. Tried `import` statements in JupyterLab.

It is possible that I am missing something basic about Anaconda environments and importing packages/subpackages, but I really thought that I was using these tools the way they are meant to be used. Any help is appreciated.