# Spacy language model installation in python returns ImportError from _mklinit (ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.)

Tags: python, pip, conda, importerror, spacy

I am currently trying to set up spaCy in my system. When I downloaded the module, no errors are being shown. However, upon downloading a language model (specifically, the english one), I got an error. The output is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import numpy  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried reinstalling my spaCy package, but still end up getting the same error. How do I deal with this?

I am using Python 3.7.1. Tried downloading using `pip install -U spacy` and `conda install -c conda-forge spacy`. I have also tried validating with `python -m spacy validate`, and it also returns the same error from above.

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, I tried downloading the English Language model using `python -m spacy download en`

Comment: If you look at where exactly the error is raised, it seems like this might actually be a problem with `numpy`? So maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling `numpy`. Otherwise, if you search for that error, you'll find more details and suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778066/importerror-dll-load-failed-when-importing-numpy-installed-in-conda-virtual-env

Comment: It did seem that it was the culprit!! `pip uninstall numpy` and a  simple `pip install numpy` did solve the problem for me. I was too focused on the `from . import_mkilinit ` that I overlooked this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Did not work for me, sadly. Any further clue what the problem is with Numpy? What's the last non-broken version?

Comment: @bythenumbers I really can't answer most of the questions you are posing there, but what I can say is at the moment, I am currently working with numpy version ```1.16.2``` with python version ```3.7.1``` (still no problems with it so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Ines Montani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6400719/ines-montani) for pointing this out!

It did seem that a quick reinstallation of numpy helps solve the problem. However, what I did realize is that:

Using `pip uninstall numpy` and simple `pip install numpy` solves the problem.

However:

Using `conda remove --force numpy` and `conda install numpy` does not solve the problem for me.