# Error trying to run pytest for the first time

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda, pytest

I am trying to learn how to use pytest and when I do my pytest test_map_func.py (name of the file) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\coult\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: couldn't find the specified module (translated from spanish)
```

Then I get a lot of lists with directories and again this piece of code:

```
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: couldn't find the specified module (translated from spanish)
```

Thanks to all the people who could help me :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: DLL load failed when importing Numpy installed in conda virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778066/importerror-dll-load-failed-when-importing-numpy-installed-in-conda-virtual-env)

Comment: man thanks a lot :-)))))

Answer (score 1):

I just did the following and it worked (solution 100% noob):

pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy

then I run my test file again and TACHAN! it worked :D