# I have aproblem to launch Python Script

Tags: python-3.x

I try to launch Python script but I have the follow error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\marco\Desktop\python\classify.py", line 11, in 
>       import pandas as pd   File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line
>   17, in 
>       "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies) ImportError: Unable to import required
>   dependencies: numpy: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare il modulo
>   specificato.

Can someone help me?Thanks

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\marco\Desktop\python\classify.py", line 11, in 
>       import pandas as pd   File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line
>   17, in 
>       "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies) ImportError: Unable to import required
>   dependencies: numpy: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare il modulo
>   specificato.

Comment: Is numpy property installed ?

Comment: yes, it is. I do that using "conda install -y numpy" command

Comment: Try the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778066/importerror-dll-load-failed-when-importing-numpy-installed-in-conda-virtual-env) thread, they seem to have the same dll errors