# Built Opencv from source successfully, but can't import to python in anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I want to use opencv with GPU in order to speed things up. So I followed some tutorials on how to build opencv from source along with CUDA and cudnn.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjXkW0-4gME&list=WL&index=5&t=541s) without any problem, until the part where he

`import cv2`
in his terminal

My terminal showed that it can't find cv2 in the python environment.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I looked for the reason of this and found some clues.
This [post](https://answers.opencv.org/question/235491/error-importing-cv2-after-compiling-opencv-from-source-python/) showed that he encountered the same problem as mine.

Starting from not having `binding` folder in OpenCV.lsn after creating build folder with Cmake GUI
[image: Image here]

Also, I do not have python2 or python3 under To build session of my `build/bin/release/opencv_version_win32.exe`, instead they are in unavailable session.
[image: Image here]

However, for hours of trying to find valid solution, I still can't find anything that can help me. So I hope there are someone who also faced this problem and can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I have found something very interesting. I have seen many suggestions through stackoverflow, github and opencv official website about missing python interpreter and related libraries.

So I just wanted to try it out and found out that my **numpy** is missing from the base python interpreter and show the below error when I tried to import numpy.

[The error is the same as this post (I can't reproduce the error anymore, so I will link it for you to see)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778066/importerror-dll-load-failed-when-importing-numpy-installed-in-conda-virtual-env)

> In order to check this, you cannot just import numpy from base environment. You have to go to `C:\{MY DIRECTORY}\anaconda3\python.exe`, click the file python.exe and try to import numpy

I have never noticed this before, since I always work within my virtual environment created by Anaconda so numpy is already there. (I do not know if this is always the case for everyone who encounters this problem and I do not know if this is the same solution for those who do not use anaconda)

All I have to do is finding the path to my Anaconda base library (in my case is)

`C:\{MY DIRECTORY}\anaconda3\Library\bin`

copy the path and add it to the system PATH.

After that, I redo the CMake buiding process again and **everything works**!!!

Hope this help some others who face the same problem.